# Angular 6: LocalStorage.removeItem won't work when closing the browser

Tags: angular, typescript, session, browser, local-storage

I'm using localStorage to keep user data and token alive when refreshing and moving between pages. I want that when a user close the browser page, the localStorage clear all data. I'm using ngOnDestroy and HostListener but none of them are working.
This is my code:

**EDIT:** I tried to replace the localStorage with sessionStorage but it didn't work either. I updated the code below

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  private authUserService: AuthUserService

  // clear sessions after windows is closed
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    this.authUserService.logout();
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy () {
    this.authUserService.logout();
  }
}
```

**auth-user.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';
import { SessionStorage } from 'sessionstorage';

export class AuthUserService implements OnDestroy {

  private user: IUser;
  public errorMessage: string;
  isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasToken());

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  // store the session and call http get
  login(id: number) {
    this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(
      user => {
        this.user = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));

        sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'JWT');
        this.isLoginSubject.next(true);
      },
      error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }

   // if we have token the user is loggedIn
   // @returns {boolean}
  private hasToken() : boolean {
    return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  // @returns {Observable<T>}
  isLoggedIn() : Observable<boolean> {
   return this.isLoginSubject.asObservable();
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.isLoginSubject.next(false);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.logout();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the logout function is actually being called (event is being captured)?

Comment: how can I do that? even if I put debugger, when I close the window I can't catch the event

Comment: I tried to put a debugger there and when I closed the tab nothing happen. Is it suppose to stop after I click on the x and not actually close the tab?

Comment: Well then i guess there's your problem because if you place a debugger inside the eventlistener or logout function, it should finish the execution and then close the window.

Comment: What can be the problem? I saw many posts here on stackoverflow and I copied what worked for others so why it's not working here? I added now OnDestroy to app component and even this isn't working

Comment: Do you need to use local storage? You could use session storage instead. It gets cleared when you close a tab or browser.

Comment: It's work the same? and what happen if I refresh the page or moving between pages in the program? it won't clear? if so I'll try it

Comment: It would be better if you can create the demo at stackblitz.

Comment: Refesh is not a problem. What do you mean by moving between pages? Do you mean different tabs? Each tab has its own session, so that won't work.

Comment: I tried to change the token to sessionStorage but it didn't work. Maybe I don't have the correct package? I tried to search on google but I didn't find the package for it, I found similar ones like angular-web-storage. Is this the one?

Comment: They should be completely interchangable. Not sure what you are using for the local storage, but I'd guess you are using the StorageServiceModule. Then (probably) in your app.component.ts is a line like this: import {LOCAL_STORAGE, WebStorageService} from 'angular-webstorage-service';. Replace 'LOCAL_STORAGE' with 'SESSION_STORAGE'.

Comment: no, I'm using @ngx-pwa/local-storage for localStorage for angular 6: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage  so I don't have any configurations in my app.component. I only import this in my component